# Accessing Data While searchDisplayController is Active

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My iPhone app is using Core Data, UISearchBar, UISearchDisplayController, UITableView and UIActionSheet. When no search is being performed, I can determine which row was selected by the user, but if a search is active and selection made by the user of a specific row, how does one determine what row was selected by the user?

Example: The following code works without error when NO SEARCH is ACTIVE:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Event *event = (Event *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];    
    [self showURL:[NSURL URLWithString:event.siteSite] withTitle:@""];
```

but, the URL is NULL if I use the above method to determine the corresponding "event.siteSite" or URL, while `[self.searchDisplayController isActive]` equates 
to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `UISearchDisplayController` you get a second tableview super imposed on the first. It is that tabelview you have to query to find out which row was selected.

See the [UISearchDisplayController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: I've reviewed the Class Reference before. Do you have any examples?

Comment: OK, I found the solution for the issues mentioned above. Instead of trying to access the value for the URL from a filtered tableview via a method that only applies to the original tableview, the correct URL is accessed from the the managedObject, which persists across filtered and non-filtered views. Thanks so much for your suggestion TechZen.